# Update value inside array of object in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a notification schema in mongoose:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var notificationSchema = new schema({
    createdOn:{type: Date, default: Date.now},
    createdBy:{type: String, required:true},
    sentTo:{type: Array, required:true},
    content:{type:Object}
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('notification',notificationSchema);
```

data would be like this :

```json
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6350dee274edf5586dc86099"),
        "sentTo" : [
            {
                "username" : "user1",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user2",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user3",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user4",
                "status" : 0
            }
        ],
        "status" : 0,
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2022-10-20T05:38:42.656Z"),
        "createdBy" : "system",
        "content" : {
            "text" : "This is content"
        }

    }
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6350dee274edf5586dc86099"),
        "sentTo" : [
            {
                "username" : "user1",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user3",
                "status" : 0
            }
        ],
        "status" : 0,
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2022-10-20T05:38:42.656Z"),
        "createdBy" : "system",
        "content" : {
            "text" : "This is another content"
        }

    }
```

Now i want to update ***status*** of all notification whose ***username = user3*** to ***1***

***status*** values

0 -> new

1 -> seen

2 -> read

Now new document should look like this

```json
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6350dee274edf5586dc86099"),
        "sentTo" : [
            {
                "username" : "user1",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user2",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user3",
                "status" : 1
            },
            {
                "username" : "user4",
                "status" : 0
            }
        ],
        "status" : 0,
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2022-10-20T05:38:42.656Z"),
        "createdBy" : "system",
        "content" : {
            "text" : "This is content"
        }

    }
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6350dee274edf5586dc86099"),
        "sentTo" : [
            {
                "username" : "user1",
                "status" : 0
            },
            {
                "username" : "user3",
                "status" : 1
            }
        ],
        "status" : 0,
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2022-10-20T05:38:42.656Z"),
        "createdBy" : "system",
        "content" : {
            "text" : "This is another content"
        }

    }
```

what can be the query :
As of now my query is :

```js
let filters = {};
let updateObj = {};
filters['sentTo.username'] = "user3";
filters['sentTo.status'] = {$lt: 2} //only update whose status is less than 2
updateObj['sentTo.$.status'] = 1;

Notification.updateMany(filters, updateObj, function (err, doc) {
     if(err){
          console.log(err)
     }
})
```

but above query is updating the status of 1st element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`$elemMatch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [positional operator - `$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```js
db.collection.update({
  "sentTo": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "username": "user3",
      "status": {
        "$lt": 2
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "sentTo.$.status": 1
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wp8qInrYt5y)

Comment: I did the same but it's not working as you can see in question i already mentioned there my solution in mongoose. One more thing , there is also a filter with status < 2

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the filter. Then you have to use `$elemMatch`. I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Thank you sir!. $elemMatch was missing in my query.